# Sphinx fails on SELECT `field` <> 0.0

Tags: sphinx

In a table with some fields built for testing, we can select `field` = 0.0 but not <> 0.0

Table contents:

```
| id     | lower_name         | sphinx_internal_id | sphinx_internal_class | sphinx_deleted | latt     | lngt     | status_hash | uploaded_as_hash | wifi |
| 119626 | lekarna novo mesto |              23925 | Spot                  |              0 | 0.000000 | 0.400000 |    75439824 |         21396735 |    0 |
| 119627 | lekarna novo mesto |              23925 | Spot                  |              0 | 0.000000 | 1.700000 |    75439824 |         21396735 |    0 |
2 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Example output:

```
>  SELECT * FROM `spot_core`, `spot_delta` WHERE `latt` = 0.0;
| id     | lower_name         | sphinx_internal_id | sphinx_internal_class | sphinx_deleted | latt     | lngt     | status_hash | uploaded_as_hash | wifi |
| 119626 | lekarna novo mesto |              23925 | Spot                  |              0 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 |    75439824 |         21396735 |    0 |
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

>  SELECT * FROM `spot_core`, `spot_delta` WHERE `latt` <> 0.0;
ERROR 1064 (42000): sphinxql: NEQ filter on floats is not (yet?) supported near '0.0'

>  SELECT * FROM `spot_core`, `spot_delta` WHERE `latt` != 0.0;
ERROR 1064 (42000): sphinxql: NEQ filter on floats is not (yet?) supported near '0.0'

>  SELECT * FROM `spot_core`, `spot_delta` WHERE `latt` != 0;
Empty set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

>  SELECT * FROM `spot_core`, `spot_delta` WHERE `latt` <>  0;
Empty set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: We're currently trying a workaround based on the suggestion from @barryhunter and tried reporting a bug (possibly regression?) here: http://sphinxsearch.com/bugs/view.php?id=2121

Answer (score 1):

Can do

```
SELECT *,IF(latt<>0.0,1,0) AS myint FROM `spot_core`, `spot_delta` WHERE myint = 1;
```

The IF() function implements the threshold required for comparing floats.

Comment: Thanks, tried and by using 1.0 (not 1) we got this to work. Now to get this hack(?) into Thinking Sphinx is another beef...